# How to install hstore in Postgresql on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, postgresql, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install hstore in Postgres on Mac OSX 10.9, but I'm having major troubles with it. First I had some trouble getting psql to work after installing postgresql using brew, so I finally installed Postgres using [postgresql.app](http://postgresapp.com/). After that I logged into psql, created a database and tried creating the hstore extension using `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`, which throws me an error saying `ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.2/share/postgresql/extension/hstore.control": No such file or directory`.

I guess that path refers to a brew install, which doesn't exist (I uninstalled the brew version). Would anybody know how I can still install the hstore extension now?

I'm rather lost here, so all tips are welcome!

Comment: This question is copied & pasted from this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21657212/398670 . Please don't clone your posts. I don't blame you for being lost, the OS X packaging situation for PostgreSQL is a horrible mess, with too many different packages floating around. Alas, the PostgreSQL project cannot force anyone to stop packaging PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually uninstall the Brew version fully. The PostgreSQL you are connected to is using `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.2/share/postgresql/` as `$libdir`, which is a Homebrew path.

I'd say you just unlinked it from /usr/local, you didn't really uninstall it, and it's still running quite happily.

Even if you actually deleted it, on Mac OS X (like most OSes except Windows) you can delete a file that's still open - so PostgreSQL can potentially be still running, even though the files have been deleted. The OS will really delete them when they are closed.

Comment: I thought that as well, but the folder `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/` doesn't even exist, let alone anything below that. I guess that I really uninstalled the brew version of postgres. Or do you think it still exists after all? In that case, would you have any idea how to uninstall it?

Comment: btw: I tried a simple 'brew uninstall postgresql', but that results in `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql`. Any ideas how I could uninstall it fully?

Comment: @kramer65 See edit. Reboot, kill the postgresql processes associated with that install, or use launchd to stop the deleted PostgreSQL instance.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed still running. I killed it, started postgresql.app, and now i finally managed to install hbase. Thanks a million!